# How to use Playwright Sharp in F# for Browser Automation

Tags: f#, playwright-sharp

I guess this is a classic C# to F# conversion I haven't quite got my head around.

I am trying to automate a browser using the quick start

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro

The C# code is

```
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GotoAsync("http://www.bing.com");
await page.ScreenshotAsync(path: outputFile);
```

I've made a start but getting a bit lost already.

```
let playwright: Playwright = PlaywrightSharp.Playwright.CreateAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Incorrect type. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'Playwright'    
but here has type
    'Async<IPlaywright>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a F#'s built-in support for [async computation expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async). The translation would look something like this:

```
let (~~) = Async.AwaitTask

async {
    use! playwright = ~~Playwright.CreateAsync()
    let! browser = ~~playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync()
    let! page = ~~browser.NewPageAsync()
    do! ~~page.GoToAsync("http://www.slashdot.com") |> Async.Ignore
    do! ~~page.ScreenshotAsync(outputFile) |> Async.Ignore
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

There are a few subtleties here that you'll need to know about:

- F# has its own async type, called `Async<'T>`. I've used `Async.AwaitTask` to convert from C#-style tasks, and defined a prefix operator, `~~`, to make this look a bit cleaner.
- F# doesn't support `DisposeAsync` in `async` computation expressions [yet](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/866), so the browser doesn't get disposed of properly. If you want, you can add `do! browser.DisposeAsync().AsTask() |> Async.AwaitTask` at the end of the block to do this manually.
- F# requires us to explicitly ignore unwanted return values, which I've done via `Async.Ignore`.

Comment: thank you.  It works , I can't quite get my head around why/ how it works.  If I try it in a function that is not in an async block with something like do page.FillAsync("#myselector","value")  |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore , it doesn't work at all - why? ( excuse my ignorance )

Comment: One important aspect of F# async code is that it creates a computation but doesn't actually execute it until you send it to `Async.RunSynchronously` (or one of the other [similar functions](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#section0)). C# tasks, by contrast, start automatically. For more details, check out "Control flow differences" in [this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TaskBuilder framework https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs

dotnet add package Taskbuilder.fs

and write

```
task {    
    use! playwright =  Playwright.CreateAsync() 
    let! browser =  playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync()
    let! page = browser.NewPageAsync()
    
    let! response = page.GoToAsync("http://www.bing.com")
    let! title =  page.GetTitleAsync()

    printfn "%s" title

}
|> Task.WaitAll
```

Answer (score 2):

As of F# 6, tasks are now natively supported through the [task computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions). The syntax will be almost identical to the async computation expression from Brian Berns's answer, except that you no longer need to call `Async.AwaitTask` on each `let!`, `use!`, or `do!` binding.

```fs
let screenshotTask =
  task {
    use! playwright = Playwright.CreateAsync ()
    use! browser = playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync ()
    let! page = browser.NewPageAsync ()
    let! _ = page.GotoAsync "https://www.bing.com"
    let! _ = page.ScreenshotAsync (PageScreenshotOptions(Path = "screenshot.png"))
    return ()
  }
screenshotTask.Wait ()
```

Comment: With `do! browser.CloseAsync()` it does not hang.